# What is android?

Tags: android

What is android?I just want to know what actually android is and what is so hype about that??

Comment: Android is an operating system developed by google for mobile devices. You can look up more information over here www.android.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google. It is similar to Apple's iOS or Microsoft's Windows Phone 7 operating systems.